# Minimize trace of $A$ given that $A-N$ is positive semi-definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, trace

I'm currently working on a problem in harmonic analysis and came across the following linear algebra problem:

Suppose $A$ and $N$ are two positive semi-definite operators on $\mathbb C^4$ such that $\text{trace}(N)=1$, I want to minimize $\text{trace(A)}$ subject to the constraint that $A-N$ is positive semi-definite. Is there a general method to trace optimization for operators on $\mathbb C^n$?

Comment: Over the reals, we would have the following semidefinite program (SDP) in $\mathrm X$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X)\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X - \mathrm M \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

where $\mbox{tr} (\mathrm M) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A-N$ is psd, $\text{trace}(A-N)\geq 0$. Thus $\text{trace}(A)\geq \text{trace}(N)=1$. Equality holds if and only if $A=N$, since any non-zero psd matrix has strictly positive trace. (Thanks to user1551 for pointing out the last sentence.)

Comment: +1, but as every nonzero PSD matrix has a positive trace, the minimiser is unique.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, incorporated it above.

Comment: Hi guys, I wanted to ask what if $A$ is positive definite diagonal matrix, but $N$ is positive definite not necessarily $tr(N)=1$?

Comment: \begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm X)\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm X - \mathrm M \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}  where $X$ and $M$ are pd matrices, and $X$ is diagonal