# Minimize trace of $A$ given that $A−N$ is positive semi-definite and $A$ is diagonal

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, trace

\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{tr} (\mathrm A)\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A - \mathrm N \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array} where $A$ and $N$ are pd matrices, and $A$ is diagonal.

There is a related post: [Minimize trace of $A$ given that $A-N$ is positive semi-definite.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250901/minimize-trace-of-a-given-that-a-n-is-positive-semi-definite) . However, in that case $A$ is not diagonal thus, $tr(A)=tr(N)$ is possible, while in current case not.

For $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, I believe $\min tr(A)=\sum n_{ij}$, however for $A\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ we have inequality $\min tr(A)\leq\sum n_{ij}$. Can you please help with analytical approach so solve it

Comment: $A =\lambda_{max}(N)I$ is feasible, so $n \lambda_{max}(N)$ is an obvious bound. I do not see an easy way to get a tighter bound.

Comment: If $N=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1  & -1\\1  & 2 &1 \\-1  & 1  &2\end{bmatrix}>0$, then $n\lambda_{max}(N)=11.1963$. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}4 &   &  \\   & 3 &  \\   &    &3\end{bmatrix}$, then $A-N\geq 0$ and $trace(A)=10$

Comment: if $A=\begin{bmatrix}4 &   & \\  & 3 & \\  &   &2\end{bmatrix}$, then again $A-N\geq 0$ and $trace(A)=9$. I think this is minimum, but I don't have a proof

Comment: if $N$ is one of following structures $\begin{bmatrix}+& +  & +\\+  & + &+ \\+  & +  &+\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}+& -  & +\\-  & + &- \\+  & -  &+\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}+& -  &-\\-  & + &+ \\-  & +  &+\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}+& +  & -\\+  & + &- \\-  & -  &+\end{bmatrix}$, then I believe $\min tr(A)=\sum n_{ij}$.

Comment: if $N$ is one of following structures $\begin{bmatrix}+& +  & -\\+  & + &+ \\-  & +  &+\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}+& -  & +\\-  & + &+ \\+  & +  &+\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}+& +  &+\\+ & + &- \\+ & -  &+\end{bmatrix}$, then I believe $\min tr(A)=\sum |n_{ij}|-4|n_{12}| $, assuming $|n_{12}|\leq |n_{13}| \leq |n_{23}|$.